# Stacking images on top of each other in a centered, responsive div

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have the following code. It is set up so that the images are responsive (scale with the window size) and positioned centrally, both horizontally and vertically. It was working fine until I wanted to add several images stacked on top of each other to play as a slideshow (fade-in, fade-out). I had to position the img tags "absolute". And it obviously collapsed the parent divs. Basically I want an alternative method to stack images on top of each other without using absolute positioning.

```
<div class="container">

            <div class="main-picture-wrapper">
                 <div class="main-picture">
                      <img id="front" src="img/VR-front.png" class="">
                      <img id="side" src="img/VR-side.png" class="">

                 </div>
             </div>
  </div>

 .container {
  height:100%;
  text-align: center;
  font:0/0 a;
    }

 .container:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;    
}

.main-picture-wrapper {
    margin-top: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px/1;
    width:70%;
    left:0;      
}

.main-picture {
 width:100%;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

.main-picture img {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;    

}
```

Comment: do you have a fixed height for the slideshow images?

Comment: No. That is the whole point. Images' height and width are completely responsive to the windows size.

Answer (score 3):

As k185 suggested, **flexbox** is the way, along with **absolute positioning**. As today it's [compatible with most of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Keeping your markup and style, a good starting point could be something like this:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.main-picture {
  ...
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-picture img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/sinayiloge/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have compatibility problem, you can always use flexbox solutions. You can check this website, it has some good examples 
http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/